# Applied Linear Algebra Exercise: Determining Input When Control is Limited to One Period

Tags: linear-algebra

I working through Boyd and Vandenberghe's *Applied Linear Algebra*.  I'd like to check if my solution to exercise 11.19 is correct.  Here is the problem:

[image]

I start with:
\begin{equation*}
x_{K+1} = Ax_K + u_K = A^K x_1 + u_k.
\end{equation*}

For $K < N-1$:
\begin{equation*}
x^{des} = x_N = A x_{N-1} + u_{N-1} = A x_{N-1} = A^{N-K-1} x_{K+1} = A^{N-K-1}(A^K x_1 + u_K). 
\end{equation*}

Rearranging the expression above (and assuming $A$ is non-singular), we have:
\begin{equation*}
u_K = A^{K+1-N} x^{des} - A^K x_1 = A^K(A^{1-N} x^{des} - x_1). 
\end{equation*}

Substitution shows this expression also holds if $K = N-1$.

I think my solution is correct, but when I write a Python script implementing it, I almost always find $x_N \neq x^{des}$ (in fact, they're not even close to equal).  I've tried solving the problem several times and end up with the same result, so I'm not sure if my math is wrong or my code is wrong.  Can someone please advise if my solution is correct and, if it is not, please let me know where I made a mistake.

Many thanks!

Doug

Answer (score 1):

The following may be of some use.

I implemented a Python calculation with a simulation (please see below) and seem to be getting the correct result.  I think what is happening is an indexing issue.  In particular, I believe that the $u_{K}$ should be applied at the $K+1$ timestep to correctly update $x_{K+1}$.  However, I think what you have calculated appears to be the correct value for $u_{K}$, or at least consistent with the $K+1$ shifted time step.

I hope this helps.

```
# Stack exchange code:
import numpy as np

A = np.array([
    [ 1,   3],
    [ 0.2,   1]
])

print('---')
print('A = ', A)

# x_des = x_N
x_des = np.array([
    [ 1],
    [ 2]
])

print('---')
print('x_des = ', x_des)

x_1 = np.array([
    [ 0.5],
    [ 0.7]
])

print('---')
print('x_1 = ', x_1)

K=5
N=10

A_KN = np.linalg.matrix_power(A, K-N+1)
A_K = np.linalg.matrix_power(A, K)

u_k = np.matmul(A_KN,x_des)-np.matmul(A_K,x_1)

print('---')
print('u_k = ', u_k)

print('---')
print('check math:')

termA = np.matmul(A_K,x_1)+u_k
A_KNI = np.linalg.matrix_power(A_KN,-1)
x_test = np.matmul(A_KNI,termA) 

print('---')
print('x_test = ', x_test)

# Do a forward simulation:
old_state = x_1
for i in range(2,N+1):
    new_state=np.matmul(A,old_state)
    
# Need to offset K by one to align 
    if i==K+1:
        new_state=new_state+u_k
    
    print('---')
    print('state index = ', i)
    print('new_state = ', new_state)
    old_state=new_state
```